# Why doesn't flow detect my null check?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Having this simple code (you can try the Flow online REPL [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxjAhgZx2AMTjjAG9UwwBLAEwC4wcAXAJyoDsBzCxgUzawwAcgFcAtgCN+DduKktUPdHHbMWI9EzgsAFIIAOACywMA-AHkJAK16aANGClMTYC9dtMAlGR6Vf1KDAdAEIDYzAAMgiwYKcsbxZeJhEWdn8qQJCwrEjouISklLTKSgyg7NyY-LBE5NT-fyZDKhwAOlowAF4wbPaaRua2nH4qQVFJfi7HJKxW4YFhOX4eAF9UNaA)):

```
// @flow
class Foo {
  id: string
  serialNumber: number

  constructor(alpha: ?Object, beta: ?Object) {    
    if (!alpha && !beta) return
    if (!alpha && beta) return
    if (alpha && !beta) return

    this.id = alpha.id // flow complains about alpha might be null or undefined
    this.serialNumber = beta.serialNumber // flow complains about beta
  }
}
```

From my perspective, all my possible branches should be covered with a null check. Why is flow still complaining?

Background: both params can be null. I only want to assign the values, if *both* parameters are defined.
I know, this can be written tighter, but I am curious why Flow isn't capable of checking this.

Interestingly, this version works:

```
/* @flow */
class Foo {
  id: string
  serialNumber: number

  constructor(alpha: ?Object, beta: ?Object) {        
    if (!alpha || !beta) return

    this.id = alpha.id
    this.serialNumber = beta.serialNumber
  }
}
```

Comment: Flow is not clever enough :)). Just simplify you checks (all 3 `if` statements ) to `if (!alpha || !beta) return;`

Comment: Mmmh, but why can't flow infer the "flow" as these checks are pretty transparent?

Comment: They're less transparent than the proposed solution, flow would have to understand that the combination `(!alpha && !beta) || (!alpha && beta) || (alpha && !beta) `covers all case. It's not clever enough to understand it yet